# Couldn't find executable below /home/leroy/catkin_ws/tum_ardrone

Tags: ros, catkin-make, ros-hydro, rosmake, makefile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i am fairly new to this, but whatever i try i cant seem to fix or see the problem here.
i have a catkin workspace:  catkin_ws

i`ve installed the tum_ardrone package accordingly:

- cd catkin_ws
- git clone git://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone.git -b hydro-devel
- export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:catkin_ws/tum_ardrone tum_ardrone -b hydro-devel
- cd tum_ardrone
- rosmake tum_ardrone

added this to my .bashrc file: `export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/catkin_ws:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}`
and : `source /home/leroy/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

when using `rosmake` it gives me a load of messages: "No Makefile in package catkin"  this goes for every package

i noticed there wasnt a makefile. so i tried adding one manually with this line in it: `include $(shell rospack find mk)/cmake.mk`    this still doesn`t change anything

when i am trying to run any of the 3 nodes in this package i get the following error: "Couldn't find executable below /home/leroy/catkin_ws/tum_ardrone"

ive also found a solution on this site where was stated that `rosmake` doesnt alway coop with catkin and therefore sometimes only `make` needs to be used. this gives me the following:

- cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
- The C compiler identification is GNU
- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
- Detecting C compiler ABI info
- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  --Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/leroy/catkin_ws/tum_ardrone/build/devel
- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/hydro
- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/hydro
- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
- Python version: 2.7
- Using Debian Python package layout
- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
- Call enable_testing()
- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/leroy/catkin_ws/tum_ardrone/build/test_results
- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H
- Looking for include files CMAKE_HAVE_PTHREAD_H - found
- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
- Found Threads: TRUE
- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
- catkin 0.5.89
- CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package ardrone_autonomy.
- Set ardrone_autonomy_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for ardrone_autonomy.  The file will have one of the following names:

  - ardrone_autonomyConfig.cmake
  - ardrone_autonomy-config.cmake
- Call Stack (most recent call first):
- CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)
- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
- tum_ardrone: 1 messages, 5 services
- CMake Warning at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:409 (message):
  catkin_package() include dir
  '/home/leroy/catkin_ws/tum_ardrone/build/devel/include' should be placed in
  the devel space instead of the build space
- Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:64 (catkin_package)
- CMake Warning at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:409 (message):
  catkin_package() include dir
  '/home/leroy/catkin_ws/tum_ardrone/build/devel/include' should be placed in
  the devel space instead of the build space
- Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:64 (catkin_package)
- Looking for Q_WS_X11
- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found.
- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found.
- Found Qt4: /usr/bin/qmake (found version "4.8.1")
- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
- make: *** [all] Error 1

this is really driving me mad and i really hope somebody can help me out here! i would be very,very gratefull :)

thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194258/couldn%27t-find-executable-below-/home/leroy/catkin_ws/tum_ardrone/) by [leroyv13](https://answers.ros.org/users/20275/leroyv13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two central concepts which you must firstly understand before attempting to do what you are doing.

Firstly, you are mixing up `catkin` and `rosbuild` workspaces/build systems. When using `catkin` workspaces, you should run the command `catkin_make` to build the packages within the given workspace.

Secondly, the source of all ROS packages compatible with `catkin` must be in `catkin_ws/src/`, and not in the root folder of your workspace.

See [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) for further information.

I hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0